Colouring MapInfo polygons from Python
I'm using rasterio and geopandas to generate MapInfo TAB files. The resulting file contains a lot of polygons (~10 000).
Here is the function I use:
with rasterio.Env():
    with rasterio.open(input_file) as src:
        image = src.read(1)
        result = []
        for i, (s,v) in enumerate(shapes(image, mask=None, transform=src.transform)):
            result.append({'properties': {'rasterVal': v}, 'geometry': s})

geoms = list(result)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(geoms, crs=crs)
gdf = gdf.merge(idx_df, left_on='rasterVal', right_on='idx')
gdf.drop('idx', axis=1, inplace=True)
gdf.drop('rasterVal', axis=1, inplace=True)

gdf = gdf[gdf['String'] != 'No Data']

gdf = gdf.dissolve('String') # Combine polygons
gdf.to_file('./Outputs/xxx.tab')


This code works fine, but my problem is that the polyons in the output have no color. Is there a way to randomly color them directly from Python? If not, do you have any idea how I could do this?
